# Is it possible to configure Linux OpenMPI v1.6.5 to use multiple working directories on a single node?

Tags: mpi

I am running some quantum chemical calculations on a refurbished PowerEdge rack server, with dual quad-core Xeons, 16GB RAM, and a single 500GB SATA HDD.  OS is vanilla Debian Wheezy.  For one of the calculation types I'm running, I think I'm becoming disk-I/O-limited and so I installed a spare 160GB HDD I had on hand to try to ease the bottleneck.

In order to make use of the additional drive, though, I need to be able to tell OpenMPI to use multiple working directories.  I know the `--wdir` commandline flag exists, but the documentation makes it look like it only accepts a single value.  I unsuccessfully tried a hacky workaround:

1. Creating a new user `scratch`
2. Mounting the new 160GB drive as `/home/scratch/`
3. Setting up `/home/bskinn/.ssh/config` to default to user `bskinn` when SSH-ing to `localhost` and to default to user `scratch` when SSh-ing to the server's internal `192.168.x.x` address
4. Creating appropriate RSA SSH keys, adding to `/home/bskinn/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/home/scratch/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and SSH-ing into each to get the host information stored for auto-acceptance
5. Adding `localhost` and `192.168.x.x` to my `ompi_hosts` file and passing to OMPI with `--hostfile /home/bskinn/ompi_hosts`

If I `ssh localhost` I get logged in as `bskinn`, and if I `ssh 192.168.x.x` I get logged in as `scratch`, just like I want.  However, while OpenMPI doesn't throw any errors, it appears to just ignore the `ompi_hosts` file and just runs all processes locally.

So: Is there a way to get OpenMPI 1.6.5 to use multiple working directories?

**ADDENDUM:** I'm running ORCA computations. [ORCA](https://orcaforum.cec.mpg.de/) is distributed as pre-compiled, statically-linked binaries.  In particular, the OMPI calls are hard-coded into said binaries and not accessible to me.  So, I can't intercept what commands are passed to OMPI, except perhaps by some sleight-of-hand wherein I relocate the ORCA binaries and replace them with shell scripts. That seems like a lot more work than it's worth.

ORCA does provide the ability to pass through whatever OMPI environment variables I want; I'm only really interested in solutions on this level of complexity.

*This is a cross-post from [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/856914/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-openmpi-v1-6-5-to-use-multiple-working-directo) -- I won the Tumbleweed badge for it there (yay?), so I'm guessing it's not a good place for it. I don't have rep to migrate it, so apologies if re-posting in this manner is frowned upon.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the source and you can't modify the mpirun/mpiexec command line at all, you're probably going to have a hard time doing things the way you tried. You should profile your runs if you can and verify that I/O is, in fact, your problem. If it is, just moving to a single SSD might be enough to make you some progress, but splitting across drives could be more challenging unless you have enough room (controller ports and physical space) to build a 2-3 drive striped RAID array (RAID 0). You are almost certainly better off this way than trying to explicitly stripe across different mount points. If you don't have the space for 3-4 total drives, but you do have room for two, you'll probably need to completely wipe and reinstall the system with a RAID 0 system partition to put everything on.

*Given the update and the request, I have added this extra answer.

Comment: Happily, it's a four-bay rack machine, so glomming on a two- or three-disk striped array should be pretty easy, as long as the motherboard has good RAID support.

Comment: @Brian,  I would make sure that I/O is really your problem before you go to the trouble. I wouldn't sweat hardware RAID support, the Linux software RAID is probably sufficient. You're not computing checksums with RAID 0, so there should be little overhead.

Comment: Oh, absolutely I'd profile the performance first.  I've actually moved on to some other computations since my OP on SU, so unless/until I return to them it's not even all that relevant any more.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of launching the executable, why don't you launch a script that changes directories into the one you want and then execs your program? OpenMPI sets `$OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK` in the environment equal to the rank that the task will get within MPI_COMM_WORLD inside the code, so you can do something like

foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
total_tasks=100 # Or whatever
if [ $OMPI_COMM_WORLD -lt $($total_tasks/2) ]; then
  cd /home/scratch
fi
exec /path/to/my/chemistry/code arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Then if you make foo.sh executable (chmod +x foo.sh) and mpirun or mpiexec (or whatever) foo.sh, it should put the first half of the ranks with their working directory in /home/scratch and the latter half of the ranks wherever you were when you did the mpirun/exec.

You could also just patch this into your chemistry program if you have the source.

Finally, if these two drives are connected to the same controller, you may or may not get any additional bandwidth. Have you tried profiling your app? What code is it? Are you running it in an out-of-core mode?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- in many cases, this probably would work well.  In my particular situation, I don't think this is practical. See edit just now to OP.  Also, I hadn't considered that controller I/O might be limiting; I'd assumed (if it *is* actually an I/O problem) it was a seek/read/write problem.

Comment: @Brian, Yeah, that's an important caveat. If you don't have the source and you can't modify the mpirun/mpiexec command line at all, you're probably hosed. You should profile your runs if you can and verify that I/O is, in fact, your problem. If it is, just moving to SSD might be enough to make you some progress, but splitting across drives could be more challenging. You are almost certainly better off putting a small, striped RAID array in your machine than trying to explicitly stripe across different mount points.

Comment: Yep, figured I was up against striping for any appreciable gains, if it is in fact an I/O problem.  If you repost your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as The Answer™.  Thanks much.